# What is this sorting algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I happened to write a simple sorting algorithm, but I am not sure what this algorithm is called.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void IDontKnowWhatThisIs(int* arr, int size){
    int* minuscount = malloc(size * sizeof(int));   //new location chooser array
    int* valarr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));   //value backup array

    //compare all elements: size^2
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        valarr[i] = arr[i];
        minuscount[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if (i != j){
                //the one with the least amount(0) is the smallest value
                if (arr[i] - arr[j] > 0){
                    minuscount[i] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //O(size)
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        //place everything back in
        arr[minuscount[i]] = valarr[i];
    }

    free(minuscount);
    free(valarr);
    //total time complexity: O(size^2)
}


int main(){
    int arr[10] = { 50, 2, 13, 33, 62, 11, 30, 66, 1, -101 };

    IDontKnowWhatThisIs(arr, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

It is a simple algorithm that compares each elements with one another and counts new location for them.
and then it is copied back to the original array.

I don't think it is one of those generic n^2 algorithms(selection, bubble, insertion), but the concept of it is still very simple, so I am sure this algorithm already exists.

edit: on second thought, I think this is similar to a selection sort, but unoptimized as it compares even more..

Comment: Not directly related to your question but this algorithm will fail if the elements in the array are not unique, in other words, will succeed if and only if the array is a set.

Comment: The posted code contains 2 memory leaks

Comment: It doesn't work when the array has duplicate values, although that's easily fixed. I don't think this sort has a name, or at least I don't know of one.

Comment: OT:  regarding statements like: `int* valarr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) The heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` and `realloc()` can fail.  Therefore, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) call `perror( "malloc failed" );` so the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred ...(cont)

Comment: It's like a bucket sort/counting sort

Comment: @ikegami add the extra line `if (i > j && arr[i] - arr[j] == 0) minuscount[i] += 1;`

Comment: (cont) is output to `stderr`.  Thus informing the user of the problem.   3) the function: `malloc()` is expecting a `size_t` parameter, however `size` is an `int`

Comment: @user3629249 i do know that i dont need to cast int* to malloc in c, but unfortunately i am currently using visual studio which doesnt allow me to do it.

Comment: The posted algorithm copies the whole array (at least) twice.  That greatly increases the `O()` value, above the `O(size^2)`

Comment: @hoholee12 MSVC is a C++ compiler. You need to name the file \*.c instead of \*.cpp and set the mode to C

Comment: regarding: *i am currently using visual studio which doesnt allow me to do it*  This sounds like your using the `C++` feature of the compiler rather than the `C` feature

Comment: @user3629249 anyhow, this is not related to the question.

Comment: The condition `if (arr[i] - arr[j] > 0){` runs into overflow problems if the values in the array are big enough and of opposite signs.  Use a direct comparison: `if (arr[i] > arr[j]){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a name for this algorithm. It's clever, but unfortunately you need to add an extra step if you want to handle possible duplicates in the array.

For instance, if the array is: `[3;4;4;1;2]` then `minuscount` will be `[2;3;3;0;1]` and the two `4` will be put in the same cell in `arr`, resulting in the final array `[1;2;3;4;2]` where that final `2` is leftover from the original array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't known a name either. I would call it RankSort, because it computes the rank of every element, in order to permute them to their sorted location.

This sort is not very attractive because

- it takes two extra arrays, one for the ranks and one as a buffer for permutation (the buffer can be avoided by implementing the permutation in-place);
- as said by others, possible equal elements require special handling, namely a lexicographical comparison on value then index. This has a cost;
- it performs all N² comparisons. (This can be reduced to N(N-1)/2 by updating the rank of the largest element.)

Comment: I still think it is an interesting idea. The special handling for equal elements is not that complex. This sort performs `O(n²)` comparisons first, then `n` moving elements around; as opposed to most sorts which intertwine `O(n log(n))` comparisons with `O(n log(n))` moving around. In a context where moving elements is the most costly operation, "ranksort" might be the best option. For instance to sort physical heavy items in a warehouse. Picking up / putting down an item is bad for your back; you want to do it as few times as possible, so finding out the final rank of every item first is best

Comment: @Stef: this algorithm is poor for a software implementation. To sort stones by granularity, I would use sieves.

Comment: That's a bit unfair - almost all sorting algorithms are poor for software implementation, except the ones already implemented in software...

Comment: @Stef: true. Why would you need anything else ?