# What is this sorting algorithm? And is there a more efficient way?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I wrote this algorithm while learning about **O(N)** algorithms, and after the last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117890/what-is-this-sorting-algorithm) I posted moments ago, I was wondering if theres a similar algorithm that already exists as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

/*algorithm designed by hoholee12*/

typedef struct{
    int val;
    int dup;
} duplicates;

int ScoopSort(int* arr, int size, int buf){

    //subarr buffer size
    buf += size;

    int* bigarr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    duplicates* subarr = malloc(buf * sizeof(duplicates));
    //subarr init: O(N)
    for (int i = 0; i < buf; i++) {
        subarr[i].val = INT_MIN;
        subarr[i].dup = 0;
    }

    //will always have biggest number of section
    int lastsize = INT_MIN;

    //big loop(until all elements are scooped: O(count of 'diff bigger than size'))
    int j = 0;
    int loopcount = 0;
    while (1){

        //min check per iteration: O(N)
        int min = INT_MAX;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if (min > arr[i] && arr[i] > lastsize) min = arr[i];
        }

        //initval per iteration
        int initval = min - 1;

        //follow index: incr dup
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            int val = arr[i] - min;
            if (val < buf && val >= 0){
                subarr[val].val = arr[i];
                subarr[val].dup++;
            }
        }

        //scoop subarr to bigarr: O(N)
        for (int i = 0; i < buf; i++){
            if (subarr[i].val > initval){
                for (int x = 0; x < subarr[i].dup; x++) bigarr[j++] = subarr[i].val;
                subarr[i].dup = 0;
                if (lastsize < subarr[i].val) lastsize = subarr[i].val;
            }
        }

        loopcount++;

        //break on all scooped
        if (j >= size) break;
    }

    //copy back: O(N)
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i] = bigarr[i];


    free(subarr);
    free(bigarr);

    return loopcount;

}

int test2(){
#define ARRSIZE 1000000
    int* arr = malloc(ARRSIZE * sizeof(int));
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++){
        arr[i] = rand() *(RAND_MAX + 1) + rand();
    
    }

    //printf("before: ");
    //for (int i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    //printf("\n");

    time_t start = time(NULL);
    int result = ScoopSort(arr, ARRSIZE, 0);
    time_t end = time(NULL);

    //printf("after: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    printf("\nlooped %d time(s).\ntook %d second(s).", result, end - start);

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

int test1(){
    //3 0 3 2 6 3 1 4 1 7
    int arr[10] = { 8, 3, 4, 9, 4, 3, 9, 5, 4, 0 };
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("before: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    time_t start = time(NULL);
    int result = ScoopSort(arr, 10, 0);
    time_t end = time(NULL);

    printf("after: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    printf("\nlooped %d time(s).\ntook %d second(s).", result, end - start);

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    test2();

    return 0;
}
```

in short, it is somewhat of a count sort mixed with bucket sort for limited memory. so still O(N^2) but probably faster than the last one..

I went from the last question -> count sort + insertion sort -> to this. I am also wondering if theres still a more efficient way (except for hashing).

Comment: This is O(n^2). Each iteration is O(n), but you have to do O(n) iterations.

Comment: @Barmar it is O(N^2) algorithm except it is supposed to be faster than the last algorithm question i posted. perhaps i didnt word it properly

Comment: I don't understand `if (val < size && val >= 0)`. Why would you compare anything about the array value with the array size?

Comment: `subarr[val] = arr[i];` also makes no sense to me. Why would `val` be an appropriate index of the array?

Comment: Several comments make reference to sections. I don't see anything splitting the array into multiple sections.

Comment: @Barmar this is a count sort with a limited array and it loops and loops and does count sort on partial subarr every iteration until all elements have been sorted out. val is arr[i] - min.

Comment: I have been playing with it and it clearly works. It is super fast for "organized" data (data that is already semi sorted) but is clearly N^2 for random data. For example, the outer loop only executes once if the data is already sorted. Only loops twice for -1,2,-3,4, ... , 1000. For 1,rand,2,rand, ... , 10000 the outer loop execure N/2 times.

Comment: As always [Wikipedia has a fairly exhaustive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) of sorting algorithms.

Comment: How is this a counting sort? It never counts the number of elements with each value. It just keeps looking for the smallest element that hasn't been put into the output array.

Comment: It also gets into an infinite loop if there are duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar -- yep -- fails on duplicates. Time to move on.

Comment: @wcochran code edited, but the point of me posting this question was to see if there were anything similar to this algorithm and i am missing out...

Comment: Since most good sorting algorithms are O(n log n), any O(n^2) algorithm is usually inferior.

Comment: If you have a priori knowledge about your key distribution (which perhaps this assumes), you can design specialized algorithms; i.e. you can beat O(n log(n)) in cases where you know something special about the keys. Here you know the keys are integers -- there are specialized sorts for these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting
Looks similar to counting sort perhaps, but I am not sure ... it obviously assumes uniqueness of keys.

Comment: @Barmar if you have a data with values that are not hugely different from each other eg) SHORT_MIN and SHORT_MAX, you could probably do it in O(N) time. ive updated my code to be able to set custom buffer.

Comment: It can definitely be done in O(c+n) time, but you can call it O(n) only if you can have guaranteed c small enough compared to n - that means it wouldn't be generally usable algorithm, but may be better than traditional sorting algorithms for specific datasets.

Comment: "I am also wondering if theres still a more efficient way" --> [Quantum Bogo Sort](http://wiki.c2.com/?QuantumBogoSort) O(1) 

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica how did you know i had a personal quantum supercomputer in my house :p

Comment: There's no O(n) sort algorithm. even fast sorting algorithms that seems to be O(n) (like count sort, bucket sort or radix sort) has some added constant in the complexity (like for example O(n + k) where k is the largest element in the array, for count sort), and this constant depends on some additional criteria, where it can make the complexity very bad when that constant is large (again in count sort, when you have large numbers, say up to 10^18).
Bottom line: there's no O(n) sorting algorithm in worst case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*test results:*

#### size = 10000000, rand() short int range:

*quicksort: took 12 seconds*

*above: 1 loop, took 0 seconds*

#### size = 10000000, rand() int range:

*quicksort: took 8 seconds*

*above: 108 loops, took 21 seconds*

its good enough for small values since its basically a counting sort, but for big values not so much.